# concatenating fields in react.js method

Tags: reactjs

I have the method below in my react.js application. I will like to concatenate
this line {dt.productCode} {dt.sizeCode} {dt.itemWearerName} such that asterisk will 
be between them.

```
        1234*xl*tester
```

How can I achieve that?

```
         renderInvoicesProducts(){
                return this.state.invoicesProducts.map((dt, i) => {
                    return (
                        <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.customerInvoiceProductId}>
                            {dt.productCode} {dt.sizeCode} {dt.itemWearerName}
                        </MenuItem>
                    );
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just put an asterisk between them as such?

```
     renderInvoicesProducts(){
            return this.state.invoicesProducts.map((dt, i) => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.customerInvoiceProductId}>
                        {dt.productCode}*{dt.sizeCode}*{dt.itemWearerName}
                    </MenuItem>
                );
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I want space between values like that, I use {' '}. [Note the spacing given in between the quotes]
Try to add asterisk in similar way and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some number of things and you want to add something between them, then `.join()` can be a good approach.

```
const things = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const s = things.join('*')
console.log(s) // one*two*three
```

You can read more about `.join` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).